# Выводит бред (@28r8590d) вместо Welcome to Tutorialspoint

Tags: java, android

```
byte[] input = "Welcome to Tutorialspoint".getBytes();
            cipher.update(input);


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ( cipher+""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: `String input = "Welcome to Tutorialspoint"; Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, input, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: @Роман, когда вы к объекту добавляете строку (`""`), это приводит к тому, что у объекта вызывается `toString`, а у объекта `cipher` тот метод возвращает какой-то адрес, похожий на указатель, что-то подобное выводит любой массив. Вам просто нужно выводить ту строку, пример в комментарии выше

Answer (score 0):

Нужно byte[] перевести в String

byte[] bytes = "hello world".getBytes();

String s = new String(bytes);

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (s), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();